# pass id through redirect with message to controller in laravel 8

Tags: php, redirect, parameters, controller, laravel-8

I have a variable $id in my controller and i want to pass it to another controller in route. `return redirect('/index/{$id}')->with('success', 'Registered Successfully!');`
the other controller is `function index($id){ return $id;` but it doesn't pass the id to index controller. How can I pass $id to index controller.

Answer (score 0):

you can use same as :

```
Route::get('/index/{id}', 'HomeController@index')->name('name_of_route');
```

```
return redirect()->route('name_of_route', ['id' => $id])->with('success', 'Registered Successfully!');
```

Comment: it says Missing required parameter for [Route: name_of_route] [URI: index/{$id}] [Missing parameter: $id].

Comment: please show your code !?

Comment: Route::get('/index/{$id}', 'AdminController@index')->name('regparent');

Comment: return redirect()->route('regparent', ['id' => $id])->with('success', 'Registered Successfully!');

Comment: change `Route::get('/index/{$id}'` to `Route::get('/index/{id}'` . Remove `$` in route